# Customizing Section Numbering without affecting Subsection Numbering in amsbookclass

Tags: sectioning, numbering, books, amsbook

I am using amsbook class. Is it possible to customize Section Numbering without  affecting Subsection Numbering as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to get the following numbering:

Unit 01-01 Some Section

1.1.1 Some Subsection

Unit 01-02 Some Section

1.2.1 Some Subsection

1.2.2 Some Subsection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something as follows:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Unit \padzeroes[2]{\decimal{chapter}}-\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{section}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\decimal{chapter}.\decimal{section}.\decimal{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
\subsection{Some Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that it should not affect the newtheorem[section]. Is there a way around?

Comment: Something like this \newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{section} theoremstyle{newstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{\textbf{Theorem}}[mycount]

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear for me what you are asking for. Maybe you can ask a new question, providing a full, compilable code which illustrates your question. The workaround of the solution won't affect (default) theorem numbering, anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but it is producing Unit 01-01. Some Section but I want Unit 01-01: Some Section. There should be colon after Unit 01-01  Is it possible to replace the period after 01-01, 01-02 with colon?